# Boole's Rule on reading gyroscope data.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximate-integration

So I've read this paper about gyroscope and Boole's rule and it said they got orientation of a device by calculating Boole's integral. I do have basic understanding about Boole's rule, but I have no idea how to implement it. Any hints?

You can find the paper here; [https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338622670_Complementary_of_quaternion_method_and_Boole's_rule_on_IMU_sensor_to_calculate_orientation_angle_of_Stewart_Platform](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338622670_Complementary_of_quaternion_method_and_Boole%27s_rule_on_IMU_sensor_to_calculate_orientation_angle_of_Stewart_Platform)

And suggested formula looks like this with []=first derivative from [], and ℎ is sample time:

[]=[−1]+[(7[−3]+32[−2]+12[−1]+32[]+7[+1])/90]*ℎ

Should I just plug in 5 data points in place of [i+n]? Does the time interval should it be same as delta time in the system? Any hints?

Thank you.